# I have never thought you are ideal. / I never thought you were ideal

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, backshifting

Is it correct explanation of an each sentence (in the brackets)?

> I have never thought you are ideal. (it's about the present situation that started in the past)
>
> I never thought you were ideal. (it's about the past situation that started in the past and finished in the past)

Comment: Don't get too fixated on this "and **finished** in the past" business. Using Present Perfect  *(**have** never thought)* always implies greater ***relevance to time of utterance*** than Simple Past - but in any given context, that might not *necessarily* imply anything about whether the activity referenced by the verb has "finished" or not. In your two examples you've *also* amplified the "current relevance" factor by casting the subordinate clause ***you are ideal*** in Present rather than Past Tense, but you didn't *have* to do that.

Comment: So, if I say "I have never thought you were ideal.", it is idiomatic?

Comment: Not at all - what gives you that idea? In fact, nearly all native speakers in nearly all contexts would "backshift" the construction *I have never thought X **is / was** Y* - so if anything, it's *your* first example that's not very idiomatic. I already said you didn't *have* to use Present Tense, but to go further, you probably *shouldn't* have used it.